# In Android, how can I find the list of packages or services that an app is currently using?

Tags: android, android-source

For example, if an app called ABC utilizes TTS, the app ABC would call & use Google's TTS library (i.e., com.google.android.tts) and Android's audioserver.

In this situation, my goal is to know all the other packages and background services that the app ABC is using.

I've checked some AOSP codes and Android's PackageManager document, but I couldn't find any appropriate solution.

How can I get a list of other packages and processes that an app calls and uses?

*Please note that what I want is not child processes.